# Type 'x' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

```
    import UIKit

class FourthViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

      var pickerData: [String] = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self

        pickerData = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"]    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: - Delegates and data sources
    //MARK: Data Sources
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    //MARK: Delegates
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

> Error:Type 'FourthViewController' does not conform to protocol
>   'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Just for testing some features but i dont get the problem

Comment: Your class works fine for me. I didn't get any error.

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Are you using swift? If so, lots of delegate methods have been renamed.

Answer (score 11):

As you have found, you need to implement `numberOfComponents(in:)`.

Your `numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int`, needs to be changed to:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Also you need to modify your `pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?`:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}
```

In Swift 3 many methods are renamed. Check [the latest reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdatasource), and be careful about [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md). And you better remark Xcode version in your question.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SrUNGYia still not working..  Protocol requires function 'numberOfComponents(in:)' with type '(UIPickerView) -> Int'; do you want to add a stub? (UIKit.UIPickerViewDataSource)

Answer (score 4):

You must conform data source protocol:

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
```

Try this code:

```
//MARK: - Delegates and data sources
        //MARK: Data Sources
        public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return pickerData.count
        }

        //MARK: Delegate
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return pickerData[row]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement all the required methods of `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` if you confirming that protocol in `swift`. otherwise it will give error at compile time.

Comment: i think you have implement all the required method!! I have check just now. So now, try like : `just remove the UIPickerViewDataSource protocol declaration Then set self as the dataSource, then implement the required  delegate and datasource  methods. Finally re-add the protocol declaration. And  then after you got error then restart xcode becoz your code looks fine!!!

Comment: "Protocol requires function 'numberOfComponents(in:)' with type '(UIPickerView) -> Int'; do you want to add a stub? (UIKit.UIPickerViewDataSource)"

Comment: @Fulachs If you go to the Apple documentation page, they will say what methods are required for `UIPickerViewDataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I got error due to the delegate method

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int 
    {
    if pickerView == stylePickerView {
        return 1        }
    else if pickerView == fontPickerView {
        return 1        }
    return 0
    }
```

tried this instead and worked

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if pickerView == stylePickerView {
        return 1        }
    else if pickerView == fontPickerView {
        return 1        }
    return 0 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this from the delegate:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```